# MySQL ADO.NET authentication method not supported

Tags: mysql, wcf, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

Recently I started a project where it is required to access a MySQL server hosted on hostgator's server from a WCF project. I downloaded and installed MySQL ADO.NET connector and tried to create an entity data model but it says Authentication method 'mysql_old_password' not supported. What should I do? I have been googling but to no avail.

This is my first time using MySQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Sincerely,
Ling!

[Screenie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzH9z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is shown when you are connecting to a MySQL database that has its passwords  stored in the old password format (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html). Newer MySQL clients do not allow a connection to be made to databases using the old password format as it is less secure.

Some would suggest to set `old_passwords=1` at the MySQL server, but I think it would be better to upgrade the passwords to the new password format. Then the MySQL connection can be setup again and your database will be better protected.

You can read about how to upgrade your MySQL passwords from the old format to the new format here: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/upgrading-passwords-from-old_passwords-to-new-passwords